# Change column flags in MySQL Workbench scripting shell

Tags: python, mysql-workbench

In order to ensure db consistency, I would like to batch set the type of the last column of every table to `TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL`.

I found out how to loop through tables and target the last column, change its type and setting the `NOT NULL` flag but I can't find how to set the `UNSIGNED` flag.

I tried both :

```
column = grt.root.wb.doc.physicalModels[0].catalog.schemata[0].tables[1].columns[7]
column.flags = ['UNSIGNED']
column.simpleType.flags = ['UNSIGNED']
```

but I get a `TypeError: flag is read-only`. I also tried setting the dataType property of the column to a reference to the dataType property of a column having the `UNSIGNED` flag (defined through GUI).

Finally I tried :

```
column.setParseType('TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED')
```

but it returns 0 and doesn't change anything (it returns 1 if I remove `UNSIGNED` so I think it doesn't work with flags).

Is there any way to change column flags (ie: `UNSIGNED`, `ZEROFILL`) using a Python script in MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use    `grt.root.wb.doc.physicalModels[0].catalog.schemata[0].tables[1].columns[7].flags.append('UNSIGNED')`

Comment: How to add `NOT NULL`? `.append("NOT NULL")` adds `NOT NULL NULL`

Answer (score 0):

TO add is whit column.isNoNull=1

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# MySQL Workbench Python script
# <description>
# Written in MySQL Workbench 6.3.4

import grt
#import mforms

# get a reference to the schema in the model. This will get the 1st schema in it.
schema = grt.root.wb.doc.physicalModels[0].catalog.schemata[0]
# iterate through all tables
for table in schema.tables:
    # create a new column object and set its name
    column = grt.classes.db_mysql_Column()
    column.name = "auditoria_fecha_creacion"
    # add it to the table
    table.addColumn(column)
    # set the datatype of the column
    column.setParseType("TIMESTAMP", None)
    column.defaultValue = "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
    column.isNotNull=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its been 2 years since the question was asked

```
import grt
#import mforms

# tables you want to skip
skip_tables = ["main_defs","some_other_table"]

def addColumn(table,name,datatype,defaultvalue):
    # skip this column_name if there is already a column with this name
    column_names = [x.name for x in table.columns]
    if name in column_names:
        return
    column = grt.classes.db_mysql_Column()
    column.name = name
    table.addColumn(column)
    column.setParseType(datatype, datatypes)
    column.defaultValue = defaultvalue
    column.isNotNull=1


# get a reference to the schema in the model. This will get the 1st schema in it.
schema = grt.root.wb.doc.physicalModels[0].catalog.schemata[0]
datatypes = grt.root.wb.rdbmsMgmt.rdbms[0].simpleDatatypes
# iterate through all tables
for table in schema.tables:

    # skip the current table if it is in skip_tables
    if table.name in skip_tables:
        continue
    addColumn(table,"created_at","varchar(45)","")
    addColumn(table,"updated_at","varchar(45)","")
```

This provides a basic understanding on how to do this